# Can't see shared folder in OneDrive app on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I have Windows 8.1. My friend shared a folder with me on OneDrive and gave me permission to edit. I can see the shared folder online, but I'm not able to see it in my OneDerive app.

How can I work with these files without a web browser?

Comment: I too have this problem. Try this and let me know if it works: Go to OneDrive app and on the right (click Win + C) go to the Settings and then Options and set "Access all my OneDrive files offline" to ON.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for an answer myself.

As others have said, OneDrive does not currently provide a means to synch shared folders into the application.

However, this feature is being developed as we speak, and should be available in the near future.

Check [here](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6325866-allow-folders-to-be-shared-co-owned-with-access-sy) for more, and feel free to vote while you're at it.

> 1/9/15 Update Quick update on timing as we know you all care about
>   this. We’re planning on making Shared Folder sync available by this
>   summer. We’ll update this thread as we get closer to the date. Thanks
>   for your patience!

UPDATE:

**This is now possible through the "Add to my OneDrive" option in the browser:**

> Hi all -
>
> I’m excited to let you know that we’ve begun rolling out Shared Folder
>   sync on OneDrive. We can’t wait for you to start using it!
>
> How does it work? We have a new action on OneDrive, called “Add to my
>   OneDrive.” Whenever you are using OneDrive on the web, or through the
>   mobile app, you’ll see this when you are browsing content that others
>   have shared with you. Clicking “Add to my OneDrive” will add that
>   folder to your OneDrive. From then on, whenever you browse your
>   OneDrive, you’ll be able to see any of the shared folders you’ve
>   added. And on the sync client, when you select what folders to sync,
>   you’ll see all the shared folders you’ve added. Select the shared
>   folder(s) you want and they’ll immediately begin syncing to your PC or
>   Mac.
>
> We’re rolling this out which takes some time, and of course you may
>   get it before your friend who also wants it (try not to rub it in).
>   Shared Folder sync is available on Windows 10, Windows 8, Windows 7,
>   Windows Vista and MacOS. Windows 8.1 users will need to upgrade to
>   Windows 10 to get this feature. Note that you’ll only be able to sync
>   shared folders where you have Editor permissions.
>
> Let us know how Shared Folders work for you – and go sync those files!

Answer (score 4):

Can't be done.

From [Official Windows OneDrive FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-app-faq):
(http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-app-faq)

**"How can I browse files shared with me and Office documents I've worked on recently?
You can't currently do this in the OneDrive app, but you can by going to the OneDrive website."**

I see so many bad decisions coming out of Microsoft.
If I was an investor I would be jumping ship.

Comment: I'd personally be satisfied if they allowed my wife to simply change the OneDrive account her OneDrive app connects to and syncs with, rather than forcing to sync with the account linked to her computer profile (so her settings, preferences, email, etc, would use HER account, but we could both use the same OneDrive account - I can't figure out why that decision was made for Win 8.1 [...] (?)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft OneDrive does not support this capability.   You can view the files and folders by logging into your online account with OneDrive http://www.onedrive.com however, if you would like to files to be visible and usable locally without a download, you will need to use DropBox or some other application.

I don't know what the real reason is for not supporting this, however a Microsoft Rep speculates it's for your own safety in this PSS article on the issue:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsync/cant-see-shared-folders-on-skydrive-website/aa016e07-367a-4be7-9a71-6580658ca2f0?page=3

Answer (score 1):

There is an app working as OneDrive extension that can show shared folders, files, pictures and videos from your shared users in OneDrive. You can also get direct links:

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/cloud-media-player/88384988-e91e-4e25-97e4-b224d6117cbc

Comment: Are you the developer of this app? This looks like spam.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this while asking myself the same question, albeit on Windows 10. If what the accepted answer says does not seem to work for you, you may need to perform the following *additional* steps:

1. Log out of and back into your windows account. (This is important.)
2. Open OneDrive settings.
3. Open Account tab.
4. Click on the "Choose folders".
5. Check the shared folder.
6. Click "OK".

After this, the folder should show up on your computer.